# What is Intel Security Assist?

Tags: security, malware

I'm installing Windows 10 and removing bloatware.

What does Intel Security Assist do, and why is it installed?
Also, (how) does it relate to the IME, and is it reasonable to believe that it provides/facilitates the provision of back-doors into the OS.  (After nearly a year, I've still been unable to find any meaningful information about it in Google)

**Update** - This question has been viewed over 26000 times, and is one of the first results when looking for  but no meaningful answer, so I'm adding a bounty.

**Old Update -** 
There have been some answers below confirming its part of the IME platform, but this does explain what the benefits / utility of the program is (particularly to the user).

Comment: http://www.intelsecurity.com/

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - I thought that was the case, I found no evidence to support it, and it appears its actually part of IME.  In the process of fixing my answer.

Comment: While its certainly possible, I don't think Intel Security Assist is McAffee for 2 reasons - (1) McAfee was already installed & deleted, and comments in http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-security/is-it-necessary-to-leave-the-intel-security-assist/8c64ba42-39a0-4908-8865-453aeb425e04 implies it relates to Intels Security Engine - ie for Corporate control of a PC or that sort of thing - only the answers are not concrete enough.

Comment: @davidgo - My answer is basically going to say, its a component of IME.  You can guess at the reason I am going to say its installed.

Comment: @Ramhound - I fear you overestimate my knowlege of the Windows world. What is "IME" ?

Comment: It stands for Intel Management Engine

Comment: http://www.tenforums.com/attachments/software-apps/23829d1436472381t-intel-security-assist-technology-access-mei.png

Comment: @Techie007 - thanks for that.  That establishes it as part of IME, but I still don't know what it does.

Comment: Does it mater?  If you want IME, the security assist service, is a required component.  If you don't have a need for IME just uninstall it, if you don't need IME, the service's purpose is sort of moot.

Comment: "but this does explain what the benefits / utility of the program is (particularly to the user)." - I specifically address the benefits of IME.  You should read my answer, and the research I provided, again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Intel Security Assist (ISA) is part of
[Intel Active Management Technology (AMT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Active_Management_Technology#cite_note-13) defined as :

> Intel Active Management Technology (AMT) is hardware and firmware technology for remote out-of-band management of personal computers, in order to monitor, maintain, update, upgrade, and repair them.
>   ...
>   Intel AMT includes hardware-based remote management, security, power management, and remote configuration features that enable independent remote access to AMT-enabled PCs.

According to some reports, ISA connects once a week to Intel servers and passes
on some unknown information.

It is not an essential service. On the Dell computer on which I'm writing this
answer, ISA was not even installed for Windows 10, although
Intel(R) Management and Security Applications are indeed installed.

AMT and ISA are suspected of using a hardware component which is baked into
all post-2006 Intel boards and which can be used to remotely control the
computer. This hardware component is enabled or not when the motherboard
is manufactured and an access key is baked into it via a certificate.
Its presence and possible access are at the discretion of the manufacturer,
but I would guess that it would normally not be enabled for consumer-grade
motherboards, being more enterprise-oriented.

AMT was intended to give enterprise IT managers greater control over the
machines on their network, which it did in a big way.
Starting with AMT 6.0, it includes KVM Remote Control to give IT
administrators complete access to the keyboard, video, and mouse of a target
client.
In AMT 7.0, Intel makes it possible to use a 3G cellular signal to send a remote kill command for deactivating a stolen computer.

However, it is not AMT but ISA which is the subject here.
To answer the questions raised by davidgo :

> *What it does*

Nobody really knows, but it probably passes some statistics to Intel.
It is unknown (but possible) whether it can accept commands from Intel
for active interference, but no such reports exist.

> *Why it is installed by Microsoft by Default*

It is not installed by Microsoft by default.
It might be pre-installed by the manufacturer of the computer,
and this might possibly indicate that AMT is activated in the hardware.

> *What security implications it has*

Probably none. It is not ISA which can serve as an attack vector, but rather
AMT. There are many reports from users who disabled or uninstalled ISA with no
ill effects, so it seems rather harmless.

As further information,
the Intel Management Engine is activated in a compatible PC’s BIOS,
which gains one access to several BIOS functions, but not before a password
is set:

[image: AMT image 1]

Within these same BIOS screens, you can perform several different low-level AMT-related configuration tasks, mostly related to when AMT is activated
as a function of the current computer power-level. If your BIOS has no Intel ME
entries, then probably AMT was not enabled by the motherboard manufacturer.

If you would like to disable the hardware component of AMT,
the GitHub project
[me_cleaner](https://github.com/corna/me_cleaner/)
might help, but there is already a chance that it is disabled.
I also quote this from the project, which I actually take as a warning
against an unsuccessful hack:

> Starting from Nehalem the Intel ME firmware can't be removed anymore: without a valid firmware the PC shuts off forcefully after 30 minutes. This project is an attempt to remove as much code as possible from such firmware without falling into the 30 minutes recovery mode.

Conclusion: ISA in my opinion is harmless. It can be blocked in the firewall
or its system service can be disabled with no harmful effects.
I would not advise on its uninstallation, because reinstalling it back
might be difficult.

References :

- [MINIX — The most popular OS in the world, thanks to Intel](https://www.networkworld.com/article/3236064/servers/minix-the-most-popular-os-in-the-world-thanks-to-intel.html)
- [Intel vPro: Three Generations Of Remote Management](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/vpro-amt-management-kvm,3003.html)
- [Intel's Management Engine is a security hazard, and users need a way to disable it](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2017/05/intels-management-engine-security-hazard-and-users-need-way-disable-it)
- [Researchers say Intel's Management Engine feature can be switched off](http://www.zdnet.com/article/researchers-say-intels-management-engine-feature-can-be-switched-off/)
  (points to the me_cleaner project)

Answer (score 6):

> What does Intel Security Assist do

It is a service that is installed and enabled when [Intel's Management Engine](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/software/server-software/management-software/intel-system-management-software.html) is installed.  As for its specific purpose: given IME's strong ties to server-level hardware, and the lack of specific documentation on Intel's website, I suspect it has something to do with hardware-level anti-tampering detecting supported by the CPU itself.

> why is it installed?

*Intel Security Assist* is simply a component of the Intel Management Engine which you happen to have installed.

> The Intel Management Engine (Intel ME) refers to the hardware features
>   that operate at the baseboard level, below the operating system. By
>   enabling interaction with low-level hardware, Intel gives
>   administrators the ability to perform tasks that previously required
>   someone to be physically present at the desktop.

[Intel vPro: Three Generations Of Remote Management](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/vpro-amt-management-kvm,3003-6.html)

The Management Engine is connected to Intel Active Management Technology (AMT).

> Intel Active Management Technology (AMT) is hardware and firmware
>   technology for remote out-of-band management of personal computers, in
>   order to monitor, maintain, update, upgrade, and repair them. 
>   Out-of-band (OOB) or hardware-based management is different from
>   software-based (or in-band) management and software management agents.

[Intel Active Management Technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Active_Management_Technology).

Comment: I based my answer on over a decade and half of using Intel hardware.  Based on the name alone, it makes sense, it has ties to detecting tampering at the hardware level.  Unless Intel chooses to document what the service actually does, this is the best answer, anyone besides Intel can provide in my opionion.  In other words, while most of my answer is based on facts and experience, I can only take an educated guess at what the actual purpose of the service is.

Comment: thanks for this - I've upvoted this answer, although it still does not explain what exactly it does - ie how it benefits the user of the computer (or administrator).   I find it strange/suspicious//bizarre that security software designed to give administrators more power does not document how it gives them power, or what exact power it gives them.

Comment: @davidgo - "I find it strange/suspicious//bizarre that security software designed to give administrators more power does not document how it gives them power, or what exact power it gives them" - Intel doesn't feel the need to document it.  If you want remote access to these hardware features you don't have a choice, there isn't an alternative, sort of like the software sold by HP for its server blades.

Answer (score 3):

Do not worry about any "Security Assist" or AMT or any other operating system component. You are screwed anyway.

From [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Active_Management_Technology):

> "Almost all AMT features are available even if the PC is in a
>   powered-off state but with its power cord attached, if the operating
>   system has crashed, if the software agent is missing"

Thus, the "Out-Of_Band" channel operates from Standby (always-on) voltage, and hidden network access is always on.

So, no matter if you remove any "malware" or other services from your OS, external "manager" can do almost anything it wants with your PC. Enjoy modern technology.

Comment: AMT is, I think different - specifically its a secondary computer reached over a correctly configured IP stack/Internet connection.  I don't think there is anything malicious about AMT, but the whole way ISA is handled feels dishonest.

Comment: @davidgo, how it is not malicious, if someone can remotely reboot your computer, boot anything, and push anything into your OS? When the network controller is always listening "to the wild", even if sleeping? Granted, the AMT requires a fair amount of configuration/authentification to start, but the claimed ability to recover a PC from any corrupted situation does not align well with security.

Comment: You contol who can access this functionality and how. There are some risks associated with it, but if you control how it works its not malicious.

Comment: @davidgo, this sounds incoherent. How can I control it if nobody knows what does it do? Starting from yourself, since you asked the question. When I used to work for a very large corporation, I don't recall if I can control anything, and crap was pushed on me every day from those who know.

Comment: I have assumed that if I bought the hardware, I configured it to my needs. If the hardware is owned by a company, then they own it and can configure it how they want. If its a byod and you let the company dictate its setup you are a sucker. None of this implies Intel are doing anything wrong.

Comment: @davidgo, I am just saying that this "technology" sounds very contradictory. Intel has equipped every PC with a backdoor with no available specifications, which defies the concept of open PC platform. If the door is hackable/rebootable by some remote elite administration, this is a matter of time when this door will be hacked with malicious intent.

Comment: hmmm. kinda alarming this ATM stuff. MoBo  manu should have build-in a screener that attends you on this such you can set it directly to "silence/block all in/external access to" this feature.